# When an animal companion does damage because of a support action, does it add its strength?

Tags: animal-companions, pathfinder-2e

The support ability of an animal companion says that they will inflict d8 damage if their Ranger/Druid/friend successfully hits something that they can reach; is the animal companion's strength bonus added to this damage?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

No it is not. Abilities do exactly what they say they do, in this case the [support action](https://2e.aonprd.com/Actions.aspx?ID=342) of the animal ([Bear](https://2e.aonprd.com/AnimalCompanions.aspx?ID=2) in this instance) says

> Your bear mauls your enemies when you create an opening. Until the
>   start of your next turn, each time you hit a creature in the bear’s
>   reach with a Strike, the creature takes 1d8 slashing damage from the
>   bear. If your bear is nimble or savage, the slashing damage increases to 2d8.

This is NOT a strike and no mention of it dealing strength mod damage is listed.

Comment: It is the Bear, found here https://2e.aonprd.com/AnimalCompanions.aspx?ID=2

Comment: Exact text is "Your bear mauls your enemies when you create an opening. Until the start of your next turn, each time you hit a creature in the bear’s reach with a Strike, the creature takes 1d8 slashing damage from the bear. If your bear is nimble or savage, the slashing damage increases to 2d8."

Comment: I posted because it would be best if you edit this information into your answer; comments are eventually deleted.Your answer is correct but could use the sourcing I provided so others can also follow the same information.

Comment: @Ifusaso sure thing, meant to go back and do that myself but forgot